# What libraries do I need in order to compile for Windows 98?

Tags: windows-98, compilers

I am attempting to compile [John Burger's StdTel](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1077/278) for Windows 98. I am using Pelles C, because it has Windows 98 support, but it appears that I don't have the necessary libraries. This is the compiler's output:

> Building StdTel.obj.
>   **C:\StdTel\StdTel.c(76): warning #2145: Assignment of 'char * *' to 'const char * const *'.**
>   Building StdTel.exe.
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__WSAGetLastError@0'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__htons@4'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__connect@12'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__send@16'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__shutdown@8'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__WSAStartup@8'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__gethostbyname@4'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__getservbyname@8'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__ntohs@4'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__socket@12'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__setsockopt@20'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__closesocket@4'.**
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp__recv@16'.**
>   **POLINK: fatal error: 13 unresolved external(s).**
>   *** Error code: 1 ***
>   Done.

So that you don't have to open up the program source, here's the relevant section:

```
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WINVER              _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 // Earliest available option to Windows 98
#define _WIN32_WINNT        _WIN32_WINNT_NT4
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>

#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I also tried specifying Windows version 2.10 (guestimated from [this code snippet](//stackoverflow.com/a/545698/5223757)), but it didn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably not linking to the winsock library.

Depending on the winsock version you are targetting, you should use either

`ws2_32.lib` for *Winsock 2* (which you seem to be using), or

`wsock32.lib` for *Winsock 1.1*

Comment: Would linking to the Windows 10 versions of libraries like `user32.lib` create references that Windows 98 would understand (i.e. are these libraries backwards-compatible)?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Very probably not - I would assume that newer libraries will also refer to newer kernel functions. But I've never actually tried

Comment: I suppose I'll have to (install and) boot up my Windows 98 VM then.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I haven't tried it, but using the Win10 libraries should work: DLL import "libraries" are essentially just lists of symbols to keep the linker happy.

Comment: Yes, any version of the import library will work. The problem will come when you try and import functions that didn't exist back on Windows 98. Your program won't start up. So don't do that. :-) If you are going to boot up a Windows 98 VM, you will need an old version of the Windows SDK. I'm assuming you have a copy, @wizz? Or an MSDN subscription? And your guesstimate was wrong. Windows 98 is version 4.10, it's just *not* Windows NT. I don't know where you were trying to "specify" that, though.

Comment: @CodyGray The compiler. I found the option to do so, but I don't think it does what I think it does. Your comment answers everything from the question (except the winsock part, which is not general advice): why don't you post it as a full answer? I have a copy of the Windows SDK, but it doesn't look much use (mostly .HLP files).

Comment: Hmm, no, the SDK shouldn't be help files. That must be the MSDN Library you have, which is the documentation, now available online. The SDK is header files, LIB files, etc. I don't know any compiler that has a setting for Windows version, but maybe Pelles C does? I've never used it. Normally, that's a linker setting, where it will write the minimum supported version of Windows into the PE header. For 98, that would be version 4. The SDK headers also allow conditional versioning via `_WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINDOWS` (not WINNT for 98), but you've already got that.